# Charset encoding convertion

Tags: bash, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, iconv

I don't understand in which charset encoding my charater is.

Here is my bash prompt:

```
$ locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
$ echo 'Ã©'
é
$ echo Ã© > test
$ iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 test
ÃÂ©
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t iso8859-1 test
é
$ file test
test: UTF-8 Unicode text
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t iso8859-1 test > test2
$ file test2
test2: UTF-8 Unicode text
$ cat test2
é
```

Can anybody explain that to me?

I got the 'Ã©' character from a curl command and I want to process the output in utf-8 character.

Comment: Don't forget that you'll often have terminal character set configuration too. Your looks like it's not UTF-8. If remote, see Putty or term settings

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack In fact, my gnome-terminal character configuration is UTF-8. But thanks for the try.